# Ambiguity in a river crossing problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics

Irodov question 1.7 states that:

Two swimmers leave point $A$ on one bank of the river to reach
point $B$ lying right across on the other bank. One of them crosses
the river along the straight line $AB$ while the other swims at right
angles to the stream and then walks the distance that they have been
carried away by the stream to get to point $B$. What was the velocity $u$ of their walking if both swimmers reached the destination simultaneously? The velocity of the river is $2.0$ km/h and the relative velocity of the swimmers with respect to the stream is $2.5$ km/h.

The answer in the book is $3$ km/h.
However, I have got a different solution:

For the second swimmer, I have divided the time $t=t_1+t_2$
($t_1$=swimming time, $t_2$=walking time).
If we put $t=1$, then $t_1+t_2=1$. If $t=1$, then obviously the first swimmer covers a distance of $2.5$ km (I have taken the junction between the banks to be a horizontal rectangular-shape for easier calculation).

Therefore, we get, $2t_1+kt_2=2.5$. Thus, the answer will be in the series $k$(velocity)$=(2-2t)/(1-t)$. The book's answer will come if $t_1=t_2=0.5$. Is my answer correct?

Comment: "...while the other swims at right angles to the stream..." : what does this mean?

Comment: There must be a missing assumptions here. What are the dimensions of the stream (length, width)? The speeds of the swimmers? There's no way to answer this without this kind of information.

Answer (score 1):

The first swimmer does *not* cover a distance of 2.5 kilometers in one hour, because the first swimmer is fighting the current. To follow line segment $AB$, the swimmer must break up their 2.5 km/h velocity into a 2 km/h component against the current, and a component parallel to AB. The magnitude of the component parallel to AB is $\sqrt{2.5^2 - 2^2} = 1.5$. So the swimmer is traveling along AB at 1.5 km/h.

The second swimmer is not fighting the current, and so they are crossing the river at 2.5 km/h (in addition to drifting with the current at 2 km/h). So if the first swimmer reaches point $B$ at time $t$, then the width of the river is $1.5t$ km, which  the second swimmer crosses in time $t_1 = \frac{1.5t}{2.5} = 0.6t$. In that time, the second swimmer has also drifted $0.6t \cdot 2 = 1.2t$ km downstream. So in the remaining time $t_2 = 0.4t$, the second swimmer must walk $1.2t$ km, which means that the walking speed must be $\frac{1.2t}{0.4t} = 3$ km/h.